# Undefined method `to_sym' for {:null=>false} in my migration: why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a migration that give me an error:

```
class DeviseTokenAuthCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    unless column_exists? :users, :provider
      add_column :users, :provider, :null => false
    end
    unless column_exists? :users, :uid
      add_column :users, :uid, :null => false, :default => "email"
    end
    unless column_exists? :users, :tokens
      add_column :users, :tokens, :text
    end
    User.reset_column_information
    User.all.each{|u| u.save! }

    add_index :users, [:uid, :provider], :unique => true
  end

end
```

The error is:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for {:null=>false}:Hash/Users/scrivoaroby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:311:in `add_column'
```

My rails version is 4.1.9

Any idea?

Comment: I'd suggest using a debugger.

Answer (score 14):

The third argument for `add_column` should be the datatype.  Instead of something like:

```
add_column :users, :provider, :null => false
```

You'll want something like this, with whatever datatype is appropriate for your columns:

```
add_column :users, :provider, :string, :null => false
```

This will also need to be done for the `:uid` column.